# simple javafx application to convert an mp4 file into mp3

Tags: javafx

I want to write a basic application that converts an mp4 file into an mp3 file using javafx, but I don't know the API's necessary to do so - if there are any.

Can you please assist me with code snippets?

Comment: Did you search for any APIs yourself? Hint: the problem of converting one type to another has nothing to do with the technology you use for the UI (JavaFX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) and a JavaFX gui.

But since it's "basic" as you say, you may as well use a batch command for it.